# undefined local variable or method `template_params' for TemplatesController:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I tried to create a model named `Template`, but when I tried to open `localhost:3000/templates/new`, I got this undefined method error in the `TemplatesController`, obviously the private method doesn't work, but why?

**Templates Controller:**

```
class TemplatesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @template = Template.new
    4.times { @template.fields.build}
  end

  def edit
    @template = Template.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @template = Template.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @template = Template.new(template_params)
    if @template.save
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def update
  end

  private

  def template_params
    params.require(:template).permit(:name, fields_attributes: [:id, :name,:template_id])
  end
end
```

**templates/new.html.erb:**

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_for(@template) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    Fields:
    <ul>
      <%= f.fields_for :fields do |field| %>
        <li>
          <%= field.label :name %>
          <%= field.text_field :name %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Error:**

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method `template_params' for TemplatesController:Class):

app/controllers/templates_controller.rb:27:in `<class:TemplatesController>'
app/controllers/templates_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  Rendering /Users/Xi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/Xi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
```

Comment: Can you please post your params

Comment: Thanks @Deepak, I think the problem is the model name, I changed Template to Page, it all works fine.

Comment: Reserved words! I suspected that was the case. Yes, I know that linking isn't always the best thing to do as some expire, but here: https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words